# Symfony 2: Get the user locale

Tags: symfony, locale

I want to get the *preferred* language of my users. I tried

> $this->getRequest()->getPreferredLanguage()

However, it returns poor results:

- [safari](/questions/tagged/safari) returns `en` every time
- [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) returns `en` and
- [[image]google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) returns `fr`.

How can I *mix* some parameters like `IP`, `PreferredLanguage` and other parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need something like

```
$this->getRequest()->getLocale()
```

instead of the `getPreferredLanguage()` method?

Comment: What's the difference between getLocale() and getPreferredLanguage() ?